# onchangeDate not triggering on cloned datepicker objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, event-listener

The project I am currently working on a project (see my previous question: [validate-dynamic-table-rows-on-event-listeners/42408354#42408354](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230894/validate-dynamic-table-rows-on-event-listeners/42408354#42408354)) where my table rows are cloned upon successful processing. I have to clear all the inputs, change the nested html objects' classes and ids and everything works fine except the `onchangeDate` event listener.

I am using **jQuery.dataTables** to populate my table and the `complete:` function is where I bind my datepickers to my original input html elements inside my tr tds. Instead of the dp126353729 ids assigned by the datepickers I use the row number for my Ids which is not a problem at all.

My issue is that I use the `onchangeDate` event to trigger the `onfocusout` event when I close my datepicker so my table row is processed with the new date. I had to play games by using `setTimeout` to get the event listeners to pick up the new date in the first place!

**The cloned datepicker elements are not triggering `onchangeDate`. I have tried to bind them to this event without any luck. Using the default ids hasn't helped either.**

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yardpenalty/vLctypmL/1/) to show how the cloned datepickers arent triggering onfocusout

Here is my code:

```
    var DatePicker = function(that){
    if (jQuery().datepicker) {
    alert(that.attr('id'));

      that.datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: 'Select a start buying date',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true, 
      beforeShow: function() {
          setTimeout(function(){
              $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 100100);
          }, 0);
      },
      onSelect: function () {
        $('.item-failure').addClass("hidden").hide();
         $(this).removeClass("error").tooltip("disable").tooltip("hide");
         $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', -1);
         setTimeout(function(){  
          //allows date to catchup  
         },0);
     },
     onClose: function(){
        $(this).trigger("changeDate");
     },
      minDate: '+1', // The min date that can be selected, i.e. 30 days from the 'now'
      maxDate: '+1y'  // The max date that can be selected, i.e. + 1 month, 1 week, and 1 days from 'now'
      //                       HR   MIN  SEC  MILLI 
      //new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    }).datepicker();
        if($(this).hasClass("newDp")){
            $(this).bind("changeDate");
        }
  }
}
```

Here you can see the that I trigger the focusout event which in turns does all the row validating and processing:

```
$(".dp").on("changeDate",function(e){
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).trigger("focusout");
  alert("onchange date" + $(this).val());
});
```

From there the event that processes the row:

```
  //Iterates thru the entire row when date changed 
 $(".dp").on("keyup focusout",function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        //reset validators
        $(".qty").rules('remove','min');
        $(".qty").rules('remove','max');    
        $(".qty").rules('remove','required');
        hasQtys = false;
        hadOtherQtys = false;
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        $(this).rules('add',{required:true,messages:{required:"Must supply a start buy date."}});
        $(this).rules('add',{UsaDate:true,messages:{UsaDate:"Enter date in mm/dd/yyyy format"}});
        var buydate = $(this);
        var num = 0;
        var dow = '';
        var delday = '';
        var quans = 0;
            flag = true;
        var qty = $();
        var Error = false;
        //console.log("dp triggered" + e.type);
        //only check date when manually entered. 
        if(e.type === "keyup" && ($(this).valid() === false || $(this).val() ===""))
        {   console.log(e.type + $(this).valid());
            $(this).addClass("error").tooltip("enable").show(); 
            $('item-failure').removeClass("hidden").html("You have some errors. See below.").show();
            Error = true;
        } 
        //check for qtys in row before processing    
        row.children("td").each(function(index){
            qty = $(this).find(".qty");
               //processes the inputs within the row
ProcessRequest(row, qty,dow);
            }//eof qty.val undefined
          });//eof td children
         }//eof error
     });//eof event datepicker listener
```

Here is a screenshot of a datepicker that is created on the `complete:` function with dataTables which fires from this function succesfully

```
onClose: function(){
    $(this).trigger("changeDate");
 },
```

[image]

Here is the cloned datepicker screenshot that does NOT fire on this function:

```
onClose: function(){
    $(this).trigger("changeDate");
 },
```

[image]

Here is the code where I clone the datepicker upon processing:

```
var ProcessRequest = function(tr, count,delday){
    var dp = tr.find("[name='BUYDATE']");
        //clear all errors
        tr.children("td").each(function(){       $(this).find(".qty").removeClass("error").tooltip("disable").tooltip("hide");  
        });
        //insert new row because we create new row off emptyRow
        if(tr.find(".itno").hasClass("EmptyRow") && flag == true){
             console.log("this was an .EmptyRow");
            var $clone = tr.clone();
            $clone.insertBefore(tr);
            //clear inputs 
            $clone.children("td").each(function(){
                var $input = $(this).find("input");
                $input.val("");  
            });  
            //destroy datepicker    
            var dp = $clone.find(".dp");
                dp.remove();
            //create new DatePicker(dp);
            var dpId = $('#table_001 tr').length + 1;
            $clone.find("td:eq(13) span").html("<input name='BUYDATE' class='dp newDp form-control-inline' style='width:95px'; />");   
            dp = $clone.find(".dp");
            dp.attr('id',dpId);
            DatePicker(dp);  
}
```

---

**Solution:** Thanks to armesian I came up with this solution:

```
var DatePicker = function(that){
if (jQuery().datepicker) {
//alert(that.attr('id'));
  that.datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: 'Select a start buying date',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true, 
  beforeShow: function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
          $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 100100);
      }, 0);
  },
  onSelect: function () {
    $('.item-failure').addClass("hidden").hide();
     $(this).removeClass("error").tooltip("disable").tooltip("hide");
     $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', -1);
     setTimeout(function(){  
      //allows date to catchup  
     },0);
 },
 onClose: function(){
    $(this).trigger("changeDate");
 },
  minDate: '+1', // The min date that can be selected, i.e. 30 days from the 'now'
  maxDate: '+1y'  // The max date that can be selected, i.e. + 1 month, 1 week, and 1 days from 'now'
  //                       HR   MIN  SEC  MILLI 
  //new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
}).datepicker();

if($(this).hasClass("newDp")){
    $(this).bind("changeDate", function(e) { // this is the missing part in my opinion
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).trigger("focusout");
        alert("onchange date" + $(this).val());
    }); 
//Dynamic binding on cloned datepickers only
$(this).on("focusout",function(){
 RowValidation($(this));
});
}
```

}
}

Comment: You will get much faster response if you attach a little working sample Html+javascript

Comment: The problem is my serverside on an as400! Can't really recreate that problem without rewrite an entire server-side program. I will attach screen shots to show what happens. Well, I guess I can create a button that clones a table row. :-)

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I could see i'm going to point out a line that I think is where the fix needs to go.

I'm assuming that in this line your intention is to bind the changeDate event to the new created element but the binding is missing the actual function that will get executed when the event is triggered:

```
// corrected version would be
if($(this).hasClass("newDp")){
  $(this).bind("changeDate", function(e) { // this is the missing part in my opinion
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      $(this).trigger("focusout");
      alert("onchange date" + $(this).val());
  });
}
```

@yardpenalty you were almost there!. You forget to bind the onfocusout event to the cloned dp. You can add the below line after `dp.addClass("newDp");` that should fix it:

```
dp.on("focusout",function(){
  $("<div class='red'></div>").insertBefore("#table_001");
});
```

Here is working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yardpenalty/mbux47dy/7/)

Comment: Ohhhh. I didn't realize I could use a callback function on the bind! Thank you! I will check answer once I am able to test this! Very cool!

Comment: See my jsfiddle above the problem still persists

Comment: Thanks for putting together the fiddle! you were almost there! Check the last part of my answer. Cheers

Comment: Thanks man you are the ish! So when it comes to dynamic event binding  you really have to bind them individually I take it?

Comment: You can bind them also in bulk like $('.common-class').bind(...) thats what your doing at the beginning `$(".dp").on("focusout".......` in the case of the newDp you only do it for the single element you just created, all other dp elements are already binded. Glad you got it working :).

Comment: So basically future newDp class elements can't be bound to an event before they exist. Thank you so much. Learned a lot over this project. Much appreciated.

Comment: All I had to do is wrap everything inside the dp.focusout event listener in a function ie: RowValidation($(this)) so I didnt have to write duplicate code.